# Add dependency jar files from outside of root project in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I would like to add **jar files** outside of root project in **build.gradle**.

I knew I can add **jar** files under root project. 
Example:

```
dependencies {
           compile fileTree('MyLibs')
}
```

It will include all jar files under root.Project.name/MyLibs

What I want is including my jar files are outside of root.Project.name directory. 
Example: On my MacOSX

```
/Users/MyJava/MyLibs/alllibs.jar
```

I did try the following so far:

```
dependencies {
           compile fileTree('/Users/MyJava/MyLibs')
}
```

But it doesn't work.

**All the above jars files are inside my local file system(My MacOSX).**

Here is my full build.gradle file if are wondering.

```
group 'try_gradle'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree('/Users/MyJava/MyLibs')
}
```

Comment: is "/MyJava/MyLibs" really the fully-qualified path to your directory? It's possible, but fairly unlikely that your folder is directly under the root folder. It's more likely that it's something like /Users/username/MyJava/MyLibs

Comment: Yep, you are right, I just simplify the path.

Comment: My full path on my MacOS is /Users/users., I just try to simplify the problem.

Comment: I update my path to reflect the MacOS file path.

Comment: What if you use: `compile fileTree(dir: '/Users/MyJava/MyLib', include: '*.jar')` ?